# Value of type 'CapturedImage' has no member 'append'

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data, visionkit

I'm trying to evolve my app to save an array of images in Core Data instead of pre-defined attributes of an Entity. Today, my Entity has 4 image attributes, and the user saves 4 images as 4 separate actions within the app. It works.

Now I'm trying to implement `VisionKit` so the user can just auto scan and crop the images one after another, and then save one time to get multiple images saved. I have the scan piece working:

```
import SwiftUI
import VisionKit

struct ScannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var images: [Data]
    
    var didFinishScanning: ((_ result: Result<[UIImage], Error>) -> Void)
    var didCancelScanning: () -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> VNDocumentCameraViewController {
        let scannerViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        scannerViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return scannerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: VNDocumentCameraViewController, context: Context) { }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(with: self)
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
        let scannerView: ScannerView
        
        init(with scannerView: ScannerView) {
            self.scannerView = scannerView
        }
        
        
        // MARK: - VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate
        
        func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
            var scannedPages = [UIImage]()
            
            for i in 0..<scan.pageCount {
                scannedPages.append(scan.imageOfPage(at: i))
                
                    let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: i)
                    scannerView.images.append( image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.55)! )
                    
            }
            
            scannerView.didFinishScanning(.success(scannedPages))
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        
        func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
            scannerView.didCancelScanning()
        }
        
        func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            scannerView.didFinishScanning(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    
}
```

And can immediately view the images in the `View`

```
LazyHStack {
    ForEach(0..<images.count, id: \.self) { imageIdx in
       Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: self.images[imageIdx])!)
             .resizable()
             .cornerRadius(6)
             .scaledToFit()
             .frame(width: self.width, height: self.height)

          }
    }
```

Here's a quick video showing everything to this point: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAC10.jpg

I'm stuck trying to properly save the array of images. I get error `Value of type 'CapturedImage' has no member 'append'`

```
for image in images {
    let capImage = CapturedImage(context: viewContext)
    capImage.image = image
    capImage.timestamp = Date()
    project.capturedimage?.append(capImage) --->>> error

  }
```

My `CapturedImage+CoreDataProperties.swift` looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension CapturedImage {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CapturedImage> {
        return NSFetchRequest<CapturedImage>(entityName: "CapturedImage")
    }

    @NSManaged public var image: Data?
    @NSManaged public var timestamp: Date?
    @NSManaged public var project: Project?

}

extension CapturedImage : Identifiable {

}
```

And here is the relationship between `Project` and `CapturedImage` entities (you'll also notice the `image1` `image2` `image3` `image4` attributes that currently work for single image saves...
[image]
[image]

What do I need to do in order to overcome that `append` error above?
Am I on the right track for saving the array to CD properly?

Apologies for the length of this post! I wanted to provide as much info as I could while trying to keep it brief. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your model `capturedimage` in `Project` is a To Many relationship, the type is `NSSet` or `Set<CapturedImage>`. And the naming is misleading, it should be named in plural form `capturedImages`.

Sets are unordered, you have to *insert* the object. Depending on your settings Core Data might create a convenient setter `addToCapturedImages` on your behalf

```
project.addToCapturedImages(capImage)
```

Please see [Generating Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/generating_code) in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately a setter like you described doesn't work: Value of type 'Project' has no member 'addToCapturedImages'

Comment: Then you have to write it yourself. As `NSSet` is immutable create an `NSMutableSet` with `mutableCopy()`, add the object and assign the set back.

Comment: I was able to add an extension to Project+CoreDataProperties.swift so that I can use project.addToCapturedImages(capImage) -- thank you!

Unfortunately it crashes upon saving with: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App.Project addCapturedImageObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2832de940'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: However, I'm marking your answer as accepted given the immediate documented error in the title :) 